# Adding two Figures to in one pdf file

Tags: python, plotly

How can I add two figures ( one `bar chart` and one `table` ) in one `pdf` file? What I am doing now is:

```
from plotly import graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
import os
from IPython.display import Image

# Chart product views
fig = go.Figure(
    data = [go.Bar(
        x=[
            "01/09/2019 - 07/09/2019",
            "08/09/2019 - 14/09/2019", 
            "15/09/2019 - 21/09/2019",
            "22/09/2019 - 28/09/2019"
            ],
        y=[15, 25, 35, 32]
        ),
    ],
    layout=dict(
        yaxis=dict(
            title="Product views"
        ),
        autosize=False,
        width=1000,
        height=600,
    ),
)

# Table product views
fig2 = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Table(
            header=dict(values=["Period", "Views"]),
            cells=dict(values=[
                [
                    "01/09/2019 - 07/09/2019",
                    "08/09/2019 - 14/09/2019", 
                    "15/09/2019 - 21/09/2019",
                    "22/09/2019 - 28/09/2019"
                ],
                [15, 25, 35, 32]
            ])
        )
    ],
    layout=dict(
        autosize=False,
        width=800,
        height=300,
        title=dict(
            text="<b>Library Shelving</b> statistic"
        )
    )
)

if not os.path.exists("images"):
    os.mkdir("images")

fig.write_image("images/fig1.pdf")
fig2.write_image("images/fig2.pdf")
```

Successfully creating 2 pdfs. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: have u tried writing to the same file?

Comment: Well, no I didn't :/ WIll try it now.

Comment: Nope. Don't work with pdfs I guess.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `PdfPages` to solve your problem. I wrote this small code for an example:

```
import matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

pdf = matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages("output.pdf")

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
x = np.linspace(1, 20)
ax2.plot(x, x * x)

for fig in [fig1, fig2]:
    pdf.savefig(fig)
pdf.close()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The example refers to plotly figures.  But these do not seem to work with matplotlib's pdf pages (I am currently having this problem myself).  Using the example in the question with the code above throws "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endStream'"

Answer (score 4):

I have been able to accomplish this using:

- `plotly.io.to_image()` to write the figures to image byte data
- `PIL.Image.open()` to read the byte data
- `PIL.Image.convert()` to convert the byte data into RGB
- `io.BytesIO()` to temporarily store the converted image data
- `PIL.Image.save()` to save the first image to PDF and append all other PDFs in the figures list to the first image

The result will be a multi-page PDF of images.

You may need to `pip install pillow`

```
import plotly.io as pio
import io
from PIL import Image

figures = [fig1, fig2, fig3]
image_list = [pio.to_image(fig, format='png', width=1440, height=900, scale=1.5) for fig in figures]
for index, image in enumerate(image_list):
    with io.BytesIO() as tmp:
        tmp.write(image)  # write the image bytes to the io.BytesIO() temporary object
        image = Image.open(tmp).convert('RGB')  # convert and overwrite 'image' to prevent creating a new variable
        image_list[index] = image  # overwrite byte image data in list, replace with PIL converted image data

# pop first item from image_list, use that to access .save(). Then refer back to image_list to append the rest
image_list.pop(0).save(r'/Users/USERNAME/plotly_dash.pdf', 'PDF',
                       save_all=True, append_images=image_list, resolution=100.0)  # TODO improve resolution
```